# How to start container with kubectl and get exit code back? without kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, kubectl

My CI tool uses lifecycles so  if Dev deployments works, it goes to QA.

I have an end to end test container that i want to run in kubernetes, but how do i get the exit code from the container?

Can i somehow run the container and get back the exit code in one command?

`kubectl run -it`
doesn't seem to get the exit code and has some extra things to say after the container is done.

Comment: Have you checked my answer. It helped you? If yes, consider to accept and upvote it so it can help others in the future.

Comment: None of the answers really help with starting the pod, just getting the exit code.

Comment: i need a way to submit a job/pod and get the exit code back.
But deployments and pods seem to get random names.

how can i get the one i just launched?

Comment: If you run `kubectl run --image=busybox --attach=true --restart=Never sleep -- /bin/sh -c "sleep 10"` and than after you run `echo $?`, will return `0` and it refers to the pod execution. If you run `kubectl run --image=busybox --attach=true --restart=Never sleep -- /bin/sh -c "none"` and than `echo $?` will return `127` (command not found). Let me know if it helps you so I can update my answer including references to documentation about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the exit code from a Pod (container) you can get the pod details with the command:

```
kubectl get pod termination-demo --output=yaml
```

Output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: ...
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: ...
        message: |
          Sleep expired
        ...
```

To know more, you can check the [documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message)

To make it easier as you wish you can run:

```
kubectl get pod busybox-term -ojson | jq .status.containerStatuses[].lastState.terminated.exitCode
```

Or if you don't want to install `jq`, you can run:

```
kubectl get pod busybox-term --output="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[].lastState.terminated.exitCode}"
```

Answer (score 4):

This way was mentioned by [mWatney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12153576/mwatney) previously, so I've just put some additional details here:

This way you can return exit code 0-255 (after 255 it starts over, 256==0) from a Pod.

`-it` and `--restart=Never` are required, `--rm` is optional, but useful to remove failed pods.
`--restart=Never` tells the generator to create a Pod object instead of Deployment.

```
$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 0"
pod "exitcode" deleted
$ echo $?
0

$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 1"
pod "exitcode" deleted
pod default/exitcode terminated (Error)
$ echo $?
1

$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 8"
pod "exitcode" deleted
pod default/exitcode terminated (Error)
$ echo $?
8

$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 250"
pod "exitcode" deleted
pod default/exitcode terminated (Error)
$ echo $?
250

$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 255"
pod "exitcode" deleted
pod default/exitcode terminated (Error)
$ echo $?
255

$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 256"
pod "exitcode" deleted
$ echo $?
0

# exit code can also be assigned to a variable
$ kubectl run -it --rm exitcode --image=nginx --restart=Never -- bash -c "exit 255" ; a=$? && echo $a
pod "exitcode" deleted
pod default/exitcode terminated (Error)
255
```

Update for LoganMzz:

```
$ kubectl run -it --rm --image=busybox --restart=Never foobar -- ash -c 'exit 10'; echo rc=$?
pod "foobar" deleted
pod default/foobar terminated (Error)
rc=10

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:47:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:39:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
10.10.0.21   Ready    master   2d1h   v1.18.5   10.10.0.21    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-184-generic   docker://18.9.7
10.10.0.22   Ready    <none>   2d1h   v1.18.5   10.10.0.22    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-184-generic   docker://18.9.7
```

Comment: Using `kubectl run -it --rm --image=busybox --restart=Never foobar -- ash -c 'exit 10'; echo rc=$?` I got `pod "foobar" deleted` + `Error from server (NotFound): pods "foobar" not found` + `rc=1`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the `jsonpath` approach in @mark-watney 's answer because you do not need any additional tools. But I will expand that if you have multiple containers, you will need to add a filter.  For example:

```
kubectl get pods pod-name -o jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[?(@.name=="container-name")].state.terminated.exitCode}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
kubectl get po pod_name -ojson | jq .status.containerStatuses[].state.terminated.exitCode
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of `kubectl get` to jq which can parse the json and print the exit code, you may skip the `-c container_name` if single container is present.

```
kubectl get pod pod_name -c container_name-n namespace -ojson | jq .status.containerStatuses[].state.terminated.exitCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to run a command in a temporary pod just to verify that my network policies are correct. The exit code of the command run inside the container should then indicate whether access was allowed or denied. For instance:

```
    kubectl run --rm -it --image centos:7 --restart=Never xxx -- exit 1
    kubectl get pod xxx -ojson | jq .status.containerStatuses[].state.terminated.exitCode
```

where 'exit 1' is replaced by a command that implements my check.

But of course, since --rm was used for running the container, the POD no longer exists after the command so retrieving the exit status fails. The only way around it is then to not use the --rm option and to cleanup the temporary pod afterwards.

Another, perhaps better alternative is to echo an output string from the command and then check the output. The command could use a 'trap' to catch any exit and echo the exit status

```
    trap 'echo EXITCODE $?; exit' EXIT
```

Above, EXIT traps any exit, and 'exit' does an exit with the original exit code.

Then get the exitcode using

```
  code="$( kubectl ... | awk '/EXITCODE/ { print $2 }')"
```