# How the pod can reflect the application exit code of K8S Job

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

I'm running a K8S job, with the following flags:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-EP
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: EP
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Never"
      containers:
      - name: EP
        image: myImage
```

The Job starts, runs my script that runs some application that sends me an email and then terminates. The application returns the exit code to the bash script.
when I run the command:
kubectl get pods, I get the following:

```
NAME               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
my-EP-94rh8   0/1     Completed   0          2m2s
```

Sometimes there are issues, and the network not connected or no license available.
I would like that to be visible to the pod user.
My question is, can I propagate the script exit code to be seen when I run the above get pods command?
I.E instead of the "Completed" status, I would like to see my application exit code - 0, 1, 2, 3....
or maybe there is a way to see it in the Pods Statuses, in the describe command?
currently I see:

```
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 1 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

Is this possible?

Comment: how about using container runtimes hooks like prestop?

Comment: I'm using the prestop hook to drain the queue, before shutdown. This will not help me to show the exit code of the previous application

Answer (score 2):

The a non-zero exit code on [k8s jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) will fall into the `Failed` pod status. There really isn't a way for you to have the exit code shown with `kubectl get pods` but you could output the pod status with `-ojson` and then pipe it into `jq` looking for the exit code. Something like the following from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61341173/703161) might work

```
 kubectl get pod pod_name -c container_name-n namespace -ojson | jq .status.containerStatuses[].state.terminated.exitCode
```

or this, with the `items[]` in the json

```
kubectl get pods -ojson | jq .items[].status.containerStatuses[].state.terminated.exitCode
```

Alternatively, as `u/blaimi` mentioned, you can do it without `jq`, like this:

```
kubectl get pod pod_name -o jsonpath --template='{.status.containerStatuses[*].state.terminated.exitCode}
```

Comment: this also works without jq: `kubectl get pod pod_name -o jsonpath --template='{.status.containerStatuses[*].state.terminated.exitCode}'`

Comment: I like the idea of doing it without `jq`! I'll add it to the answer.