# Getting exit code from the application running in a container (kubernetes)

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, containers, exit-code

I am trying to get the exit from the application running in a kubernetes cluster. I can see the pod status as Error but I am interested in getting the exact exit code.

Docker File:

```
# getting base image 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Copy powershell scripts
COPY scripts/ scripts/

# copy app
COPY app/ app/

# run script 
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:\\scripts\\myscript.ps1"]
```

myscript.sp1:

```
# Run script 1
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\\scripts\\myscript1.ps1`" "

# Run script 2
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\\scripts\\myscript2.ps1`" "


#Invoke exe
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\app\MyApp.exe`" "

# Write Exit Code
Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE

Write-Host "Exit with Exit Code"

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

On error, I can see the pod status as 'Error' but I need to get the exact exit code returned from myscript.ps1. I can see the exit code when I look at the Pod's log but I don't see it in the container exit code.

I have also tried this [How to start container with kubectl and get exit code back? without kubectl exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338886/how-to-start-container-with-kubectl-and-get-exit-code-back-without-kubectl-exec) But getting status as true or false

```
kubectl run myjob4 -it --restart=Never --image=myacr.azurecr.io/myapp:v1 --restart=Never --overrides='"{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"spec\":{\"nodeSelector\":{\"kubernetes.azure.com/os-sku\":\"Windows2019\",\"kubernetes.io/os\":\"windows\"}}}"'
```

Output:

10
Exit with Exit Code
pod default/myjob5 terminated (Error)

$?

output:

False

Instead of false, how can I get the exit code of 10 ( in this case ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only the `-File` parameter of the PowerShell CLI** ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) **passes a *script file*'s exit code through *as-is***, and using `-File` is the proper way to invoke a script file.

- `powershell.exe` defaults to the `-Command` CLI parameter (whereas `pwsh` defaults to `-File`), and it only reports an *abstract* exit code by default, namely `0` if the last statement executed succeeded, and `1` otherwise. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375) for details.

Therefore, use the following in your Dockerfile:

```bash
# run script 
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-File", "C:\\scripts\\myscript.ps1"]
```

Two asides:

- [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).
- `\` characters have *no* special meaning to PowerShell, so you never need to escape them as `\\` (PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) is `` ` ``, the so-called backtick).

Therefore, use the following in your PowerShell script:

```bash
# Alternatively, simply:
#  C:\scripts\myscript1.ps1 
& "C:\scripts\myscript1.ps1"

# Run script 2
& "C:\scripts\myscript2.ps1"

#Invoke exe
& "C:\app\MyApp.exe"

# ...

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```